# How do I tell if a type is a "simple" type? i.e. holds a single value

Tags: c#, .net, generics

```
typeof(string).IsPrimitive == false
typeof(int).IsPrimitive == true
typeof(MyClass).IsClass == true
typeof(string).IsClass == true
typeof(string).IsByRef == false
typeof(MyClass).IsByRef == true // correction: should be false (see comments below)
```

I have a method that instantiates a new instance of T and, if it's a "complex" class, fills its properties from a set of source data values.

(a) If T is a simple type (e.g. a string or an int or anything else similar), a quick conversion from the source data to T is to be performed.

(b) If T is a class (but not something simple like string), then I'll use Activator.CreateInstance and do a bit of reflection to populate the fields.

Is there a quick and simple way to tell if I should use method (a) or method (b)? This logic will be used inside a generic method with T as the type argument.

Comment: string, despite having a lowercase name in C#, is not a simple type, but rather a wrapper around a char array.  string is converted to String internally by the C# compiler.

Comment: I'm curious -- how did you get that last line to result in true?

Comment: because class instances are passed by reference...

Comment: @EricLippert at the time I wrote the previous comment, I had no idea who you were. Having forgotten all about this question, I just came across it again and noticed my flippant response to your question and realised who I was dealing with, which means obviously I'm wrong ;)

Comment: @NathanRidley: `IsByRef` is for the following situation: you have a `MethodInfo` for method `void A(ref int x)`; you obtain the `ParameterInfo` for `x` and ask it for the parameter's type. The `IsByRef` property of that `Type` should be `true`. The `GetElementType` method then returns `typeof(int)`. I cannot think of a way to use `typeof(C)` and get a *ref parameter type* out of that, hence my question.

Comment: Your supposition that `IsByRef` tells you whether a value of a type is passed by reference is clearly incorrect because you stated that `IsByRef` was `false` for `string`, but clearly strings are passed by reference. To tell whether a type is passed by reference or by value you should use `IsValueType`.

Comment: @EricLippert - thanks, that makes perfect sense

Answer (score 147, accepted):

String is probably a special case.

I think I would do.....

```
bool IsSimple(Type type)
{
    return type.IsPrimitive 
      || type.Equals(typeof(string));
}
```

---

**Edit:**

Sometimes you need to cover some more cases, like enums and decimals. Enums are a special kind of type in C#. Decimals are structs like any other. The problem with the structs is that they may be complex, they may be user defined types, they may be just a number. So you don't have any other chance than knowing them to differentiate.

```
bool IsSimple(Type type)
{
  return type.IsPrimitive 
    || type.IsEnum
    || type.Equals(typeof(string))
    || type.Equals(typeof(decimal));
}
```

Handling nullable counterparts are also a bit tricky. The nullable itself is a struct.

```
bool IsSimple(Type type)
{
  if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))
  {
    // nullable type, check if the nested type is simple.
    return IsSimple(type.GetGenericArguments()[0]);
  }
  return type.IsPrimitive 
    || type.IsEnum
    || type.Equals(typeof(string))
    || type.Equals(typeof(decimal));
}
```

Test:

```
Assert.IsTrue(IsSimple(typeof(string)));
Assert.IsTrue(IsSimple(typeof(int)));
Assert.IsTrue(IsSimple(typeof(decimal)));
Assert.IsTrue(IsSimple(typeof(float)));
Assert.IsTrue(IsSimple(typeof(StringComparison)));  // enum
Assert.IsTrue(IsSimple(typeof(int?)));
Assert.IsTrue(IsSimple(typeof(decimal?)));
Assert.IsTrue(IsSimple(typeof(StringComparison?)));
Assert.IsFalse(IsSimple(typeof(object)));
Assert.IsFalse(IsSimple(typeof(Point)));  // struct in System.Drawing
Assert.IsFalse(IsSimple(typeof(Point?)));
Assert.IsFalse(IsSimple(typeof(StringBuilder))); // reference type
```

**Note to .NET Core**

As DucoJ points out in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/863881/how-do-i-tell-if-a-type-is-a-simple-type-i-e-holds-a-single-value/38998370#38998370), some of the used methods are not available on the class `Type` in .NET core anymore.

Fixed code (I hope it works, I couldn't try myself. Otherwise please comment):

```
bool IsSimple(Type type)
{
  var typeInfo = type.GetTypeInfo();
  if (typeInfo.IsGenericType && typeInfo.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))
  {
    // nullable type, check if the nested type is simple.
    return IsSimple(typeInfo.GetGenericArguments()[0]);
  }
  return typeInfo.IsPrimitive 
    || typeInfo.IsEnum
    || type.Equals(typeof(string))
    || type.Equals(typeof(decimal));
}
```

Comment: John Saunders, below, makes a valid point, so in that light I think your answer is probably the best one for my case.

Comment: This fails for things like enums, decimals, etc.  See my answer below for a more general solution

Comment: double is also "primitive"
according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.isprimitive?view=netframework-4.7.1

Comment: @AndyPook: Yes, it is. What do you mean by that? I didn't list all the primitive types in the "tests", just a selection of a few different cases. `double` is the same as `float`, `int`, `bool`, `long`, 'byte` and so on. Special cases are `decimal`, `string` and enums which are not primitive but still usually regarded as "simple" types.

Comment: According to that link `IsPrimative` is true for `double`. So it's not "special" and doesn't need the extra test in `IsSimple`. right?

Comment: Depending on your needs, you might need to add **|| type.Equals(typeof(datetime))**

Comment: As well as `|| type.Equals(typeof(TimeSpan))`.

Comment: Also, note that .Net Core supports the .Net `Type` again to ease porting.

Comment: DateTime also needs to be checked for

Comment: If you have a look at the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetype?view=netcore-3.1 the Enum and Decimal is a part of ValueType so you could simplify what the `IsSimple` returns to just `return typeInfo.IsPrimitive
                || type.Equals(typeof(string))
                || type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(ValueType));`

Comment: @GoldenAge: a Struct is a value type too, but not necessarily a simple type (it may have multiple fields). The definition of a "simple type" is not a technical one and most probably specific to a project.

Answer (score 20):

Using a solution based on `TypeConverter` is also a nice and simple way to model this.

Say you have this implementation for instance:

```cs
public static bool IsSimple(this Type type) =>
    TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(type).CanConvertFrom(typeof(string));
```

This returns `true` for:

- All primitive types
- All enums
- `string`s
- `decimal`s
- `DateTime`
- `DateTimeOffset`
- `TimeSpan`
- `Uri`
- `Guid`
- `Nullable<>` of any of the types above
- numerous other types that have native `TypeConverter`s implemented (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.typeconverter?view=net-5.0) on the `Derived` section)

This approach works well since most frameworks support `TypeConverter`s natively, like XML and Json serialization libraries, and you can then use the same converter to parse the values while reading.

Answer (score 17):

In Addition to Stefan Steinegger answer:
In .NET Core the .IsPrimitive etc. are no longer members of Type, they are now members of TypeInfo. So his solution will then become:

```
bool IsSimple(TypeInfo type)
{
    if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() ==     typeof(Nullable<>))
    {
        // nullable type, check if the nested type is simple.
        return IsSimple((type.GetGenericArguments()[0]).GetTypeInfo());
    }
    return type.IsPrimitive
      || type.IsEnum
      || type.Equals(typeof(string))
      || type.Equals(typeof(decimal));
}
```

Comment: If somebody with enough rep could post this as a comment under Stefan Steinegger's post, it might safe other people time.

Comment: At least in the version of netstandard I am using (1.6) `type.Equals(typeof(x))` results in a compile error because the `type` variable is a `System.Reflection.TypeInfo`, which does *not* derive from `System.Type`. Instead you have to use `type.Equals(typeof(x).GetTypeInfo())`.

Comment: @DucoJ: Thanks for this. I didn't know that. I added this information to my answer.

Answer (score 7):

There is a more general type than primitive, the ValueType encompasses a lot more than primitive, such as enums, decimal, and other such things [ValueType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691141(v=vs.71).aspx).  Below is a function I wrote to identify complex types, that may fit your needs.

```
    public static bool IsComplex(Type typeIn)
    {
        if (typeIn.IsSubclassOf(typeof(System.ValueType)) || typeIn.Equals(typeof(string))) //|| typeIn.IsPrimitive
            return false;
        else
            return true;

    }
```

Comment: There is also `typeIn.IsValueType`. "IsComplex" is misleading in this case, because a struct (value type) can be complex by having many properties, which for instance can point to reference types.

Comment: I improved my answer. There is no single correct answer to this, because it depends very much on what is needed in the specific case. Sometimes you can handle all the value types the same, sometimes you can not.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to resurrect a really old thread, but since this still ranks high on web searches in Google, want to get a more direct and effective solution added:

```
if(System.Type.GetTypeCode(typeof(int)) == TypeCode.Object) {
    // Do what you will...
}
```

Comment: You should explain a little better what's going on here, i.e. why performing that particular check is useful.

Comment: When `System.Type.GetTypeCode(typeof(myValue))` is `TypeCode.Object`, "myValue" has a non primitive type.

Else there are a dozen of different primitive types.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.typecode(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This doesn't work so well for Nullables.... `>System.Type.GetTypeCode(typeof(int?))`
`>Object`

Answer (score 0):

Modified Mauser's answer a little bit added a method to check whether a property is an collection.

> ```
> public static class TypeExtensions
> {
>     public static bool IsComplex(this Type type)
>     {
>         return !type.IsValueType && type != typeof(string);
>     }
>
>     public static bool IsCollection(this Type type)
>     {
>         var collectionTypeName = typeof(ICollection<>).Name;
>         return type.Name == collectionTypeName || type.GetInterface(collectionTypeName) != null;
>     }
> }
> ```

Here inside IsCollection(..) we can even keep IEnumerable, but string also inherit IEnumerable. so if you are using IEnumerable, add a check for string also!

```
public static class TypeExtensions
    {

        public static bool IsComplex(this Type type)
        {
            return !type.IsValueType && type != typeof(string);
        }



        public static bool IsCustomComplex(this Type type)
        {
            var elementType = type.GetCustomElementType();
            return elementType != null && elementType.IsComplex();
        }

        public static Type GetCustomElementType(this Type type, object value)
        {
            return value != null 
                ? value.GetType().GetCustomElementType() 
                : type.GetCustomElementType();
        }

        public static Type GetCustomElementType(this Type type)
        {
            return type.IsCollection()
                ? type.IsArray
                    ? type.GetElementType()
                    : type.GetGenericArguments()[0]
                : type;
        }


        public static bool IsCustomComplex(this Type type, object value)
        {
            return value != null
                ? value.GetType().IsCustomComplex()
                : type.IsCustomComplex();
        }


        public static bool IsCollection(this Type type)
        {
            var collectionTypeName = typeof(IEnumerable<>).Name;
            return (type.Name == collectionTypeName || type.GetInterface(typeof(IEnumerable<>).Name) != null ||
                    type.IsArray) && type != typeof(string);
        }

        public static bool HasDefaultConstructor(this Type type)
        {
            return type.IsValueType || type.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) != null;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Strings aren't primitives, if I recall correctly. even though there is a  keyword for it, a string is  an object. Your call to IsPrimitive will accurately tell you if something is a primitive.

Comment: Yes but strings are assigned like primitives and in most cases are treated (from the outside) as though they are primitives.

Comment: Strings are kind of a unique beast in this regard.  I think Stefan's suggestion of special handling for them is the best approach.

Comment: This does not answer the question at hand and would be better suited as a comment.