# WCF: For which property type do I have to call SetLink

Tags: c#, wcf, datacontext

I want to make a really generic class to save objects to a WCF service. I get an object of any type and analyse the objects properties via reflection. When saving the object into the service context, I need to know, if I have to call the `SetLink(...)` method of the `DataServiceContext` for a property or not.

Therefore I need a method to find out, if I have to call `SetLink(...)` or not. I already tried to doit by myself:

```cs
private bool IsLinkedProperty(PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
{
    return (propertyInfo != null) && propertyInfo.PropertyType.IsClass;
}
```

But this function does not work for string-properties and maybe for others too. Does anybody has a fitting function for this?

Comment: Can you define the criteria for determining whether the method should be called?

Comment: You can find the `SetLink`method here: [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.client.dataservicecontext.setlink%28v=vs.113%29.aspx). As I understand for all "primitive" data types.

Comment: It looks to me like you will need to add metadata (ie attributes) to your properties to know when to call the method, and what to pass for the parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with the following solution. I found a hint in the [qestion of Nathan Ridley](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/863881/how-do-i-tell-if-a-type-is-a-simple-type-i-e-holds-a-single-value):

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Helper class for analyzing a type.
/// </summary>
public static class TypeAnalyzer
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Calculates if the given type is a "simple" type.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="type">Type to be checked for simplicity.</param>
    /// <returns>True, if the type is "simple";false otherwise.</returns>
    /// <remarks>
    ///   The following types are assumed to be simple:
    ///   <list type="*">
    ///     <item>string</item>
    ///     <item>int</item>
    ///     <item>decimal</item>
    ///     <item>float</item>
    ///     <item><see cref="StringComparison"/> (enum type)</item>
    ///     <item>int? (nullable simple types)</item> 
    ///   </list>
    ///   The following types are not simple:
    ///   <list type="*">
    ///     <item>Point (struct)</item>
    ///     <item>Point? (nullable struct)</item>
    ///     <item>StringBuilder (class)</item>
    ///   </list>
    /// </remarks>
    public static bool IsSimple(this Type type)
    {
        if (IsNullableType(type))
            return IsNestedTypeSimple(type);

        return type.IsPrimitive
          || type.IsEnum
          || type.Equals(typeof(string))
          || type.Equals(typeof(decimal))
          || type.Equals(typeof(DateTime))
          || type.Equals(typeof(Guid));
    }

    private static bool IsNestedTypeSimple(Type type)
    {
        var nestedType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type);
        return IsSimple(nestedType);
    }

    private static bool IsNullableType(Type type)
    {
        return Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type) != null;
    }
}
```

Test cases written in NUnit are:

```cs
[TestFixture]
public class TypeAnalyzerTests
{
    [TestCase(typeof(string), true)]
    [TestCase(typeof(int), true)]
    [TestCase(typeof(decimal), true)]
    [TestCase(typeof(float), true)]
    [TestCase(typeof(StringComparison), true)]
    [TestCase(typeof(int?), true)]
    [TestCase(typeof(decimal?), true)]
    [TestCase(typeof(StringComparison?), true)]
    [TestCase(typeof(object), false)]
    [TestCase(typeof(Point), false)]
    [TestCase(typeof(Point?), false)]
    [TestCase(typeof(StringBuilder), false)]
    [TestCase(typeof(DateTime), true)]
    [TestCase(typeof(Guid), true)]
    [TestCase(typeof(Guid?), true)]
    public void IsSimple_WhenCalledForType_ReturnsExpectedResult(Type type, bool expectedResult)
    {
        var isSimple = TypeAnalyzer.IsSimple(type);

        Assert.That(isSimple, Is.EqualTo(expectedResult));
    }
}
```

Finally I changed the in the question mentioned method to:

```cs
private bool IsLinkedProperty()
{ 
    return (_propertyInfo != null) && !_propertyInfo.PropertyType.IsSimple();
}
```