# Boring to have to add [FromBody] to all action methods in MVC controllers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I just migrated a project from .NET Framework 4.8 to .NET Core 6.

I have a small problem: since ASP.NET Core 5.0 or ASP.NET Core 6.0 MVC, MVC and Web API have been unified.

In order to call a method with a complex type parameter, we must now specify `[FromBody]`.

This is by default if the controller is an `[ApiController]`.

I have a lot of MVC controllers and methods. So it's so boring to add `[FromBody]` to all these methods ...

Is there a quick solution to this problem ? Maybe is it possible to combine the attribute `[ApiController]` with inheritance from a base controller?

Make change in front side is not better because ajax calls are not standardized and frequently different in this application.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

I think Custom FromBodyActionFilter could be the best choice for you. In this way, each request will enter the OnResourceExecuting method, and then process your business according to your needs.

**1. Create CustomFromBodyActionFilter class.**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding;

namespace _75567026
{
    public class CustomFromBodyActionFilter : IResourceFilter
    {
        public void OnResourceExecuting(ResourceExecutingContext context)
        {
            foreach (var parameter in context.ActionDescriptor.Parameters)
            {
                var bindingInfo = parameter.BindingInfo;

                if (bindingInfo != null && !bindingInfo.BindingSource.CanAcceptDataFrom(BindingSource.Body))
                {
                    bindingInfo.BindingSource = BindingSource.Body;
                }
            }
        }

        public void OnResourceExecuted(ResourceExecutedContext context)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

**2. Register the filter**

```
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews((options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add(typeof(CustomFromBodyActionFilter));
}));
```

Comment: I appreciate this answer, I was imagining something similar possible.
With this i can keep my routing and areas logic !
Thank you.

Comment: parameter.BindingInfo is null on my test case but I will continue on this way

Comment: Something is strange because on debugging, in this OnResourceExecuting, bindingInfo is Body but my complex type still empty, and when i explicitly set [FromBody] before the parameter, all is right ...

Comment: Hi @Mulaga, could you share your project for us, we need to debug it. pls hide your sensitive info, if you can re-create a new sample for us, it might be good.

Comment: Hey @Jason, i finally found an similar solution here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49396816/how-to-get-the-asp-net-core-2-0-mvc-model-binder-to-bind-complex-types-without-f?rq=1) and it worked as expected, but after real appling, this approach causes me others problems with others action calls, so I will do it case by case.
Appreciate your helps guys, thanks :)